# Spring - display PDF-file in browser instead of downloading

Tags: spring, pdf, browser, http-headers

i am trying to display a pdf in my browser with spring.
my problem is that the browser downloads the file instead of displaying it.
this is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getpdf1", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPDF1() {


    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    String filename = "pdf1.pdf";

    headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename);

    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(pdf1Bytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
}
```

i am looking forward to your answers!
thanks

Comment: Its not works for me.

Comment: Can I render a `.csv` file on the browser? What needs to be set to do so?

Comment: try replacing "headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));" with "response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=utf-8");"

Comment: I'm using this same code for image/png, but this is still downloading.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are almost done. Just remove

```
headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
```

from your code block. It should be used when posting multipart/form-data to the server.

Comment: I tried like this but still its downloading instead of view in browser. what was the exact solution here.

Comment: Solution: Code block from OP's question but without `setContentDispositionFormData`. Maybe you should post a new question.

Comment: Off topic, but do you happen to know how to remove the spring leaf icon (web browser icon) from this pdf viewer when it 's opened in a new tab?

Comment: Put your favicon at the root of your web site, e.g. http://localhost/favicon.ico. See also https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon.

Answer (score 29):

Content-Disposition to control either download or view in browser

View in browser

```
headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + "example.pdf");
```

Download

```
headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "example.pdf");
```

Comment: I'm using this same code for image/png, but this is still downloading.

Comment: but this solution was talking about PDF file, can you provide more information for your code about image/png file?

Answer (score 3):

**Below code Snippet will assist you display the file on the browser**

---

```
@GetMapping(value = "/terms-conditions")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getTermsConditions() {

        String filePath = "/path/to/file/";
        String fileName = "fileName.pdf";
        File file = new File(filePath+fileName);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();      
        headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" +fileName);
        
        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(file.length())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
                .body(resource);
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to create a live preview of file while editing?

Answer (score 0):

it's working you should try do that, get by filename and opnend in browers

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/pdf/{filename:.+}") public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getTermsConditions(@PathVariable String filename) {

    File file = storageService.load(filename).getFile();
 
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();      
    headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" +fileName);
    
    InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .contentLength(file.length())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
            .body(resource);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See code bellow:

```
headers.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.inline().filename("example.pdf").build());
```

Answer (score -1):

View in browser (use inline) :

```
header.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=" + pdfFile.getName());
```

For Download (use attachment) :

```
header.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + pdfFile.getName());
```